# reactjs fetch - body: json.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

My Json Object looks like this:

```
[
{
    "keys": {
        "_1": ".",
        "_2": ".",
        "_3": "."
    },
    "credits": -200,
    "_id": "5c1e3e7531dccf0017cf70b9",
    "firstName": "Martin",
    "lastName": "Seubert",
    "username": "admin",
    "createdDate": "2018-12-22T13:39:01.244Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5c1e3e7531dccf0017cf70b9"
}
]
```

An I want following function to set the keys to a value, I am fetching from another API:

```
updateKeys() {
  let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  var requestUrl = 'https://mighty-atoll-75521.herokuapp.com/users/';
  var id = user._id
  fetch(requestUrl + id, {
      method: 'put',
      headers: {
        ...authHeader(),
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({keys._1:  this.props.code})
    })
}
```

But i get this Error Message in the browser:

[image]

Have you any suggestions for me?

Best regards

Martin

**EDIT:**

Here you can find the full code:
https://github.com/kamami/prototype/blob/RealDatabase/src/components/ProgressMobileStepper.jsx

Comment: Use square bracket for the `keys._1`

Comment: square bracket should look as `keys['_1']`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this gives me the following error: "keys" is not defined. I edited my post and added my repo on github for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use a variable as a 'property' so you need the *ComputedPropertyName* from ES6. Try with 
    `body: JSON.stringify({[keys._1]:  this.props.code})`
instead of 
    `body: JSON.stringify({keys._1:  this.props.code})`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this gives me the following error: "keys" is not defined. I edited my post and added my repo on github for you :)

Comment: Let's try again :). I think you want to update a JSON and you're passing the `path` to modify it so it will be one of these:
1) `{'keys._1':  this.props.code}` 
2)`{'keys': { '_1':  this.props.code}}`

Comment: Ok :) So my final json should look like this:                                                                 `code`[
{
    "keys": {
        "_1": "12345",
        "_2": "6789",
        "_3": "111213"
    }
   }
]`code`

Comment: I have several Items, each with its own code. When I click a button in my App, this code should be posted into the api, so that every user can save all his purchased codes! Hope that makes it a bit clearer :) Or would an array be a better solution?

Comment: Even if you have several items, when you click a button, you want to update this `user` in particular, not all your array, isn't it? so in the `body` you should mantain the same structure that your user has, not the array. I mean, if your `user` structure is
`
    {
        "keys": {
            "_1": ".",
            "_2": ".",
        },
        "firstName": "Martin",
        "lastName": "Seubert",
        "username": "admin"
    }
`
and you want to modify the `keys._1`, the `body` should looks like:
`{'keys': { '_1': this.props.code}}` (same structure as `user` has)

Comment: Works like a charm, you saved my day! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an object with a property name like `keys._1`.

You will have to do it in 2 steps:

```
var o = {};
o.keys = {};
o.keys._1 = this.props.code;
```

If that was an intention, you can quote it

```
o['keys._1'] = this.props.code;
```

Comment: You can create an object with  the value of the property name using square bracket ie.  { [keys._1]: "some value" } @Karel Frajták

Answer (score 1):

```
    updateKeys() {
  let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  var requestUrl = 'https://mighty-atoll-75521.herokuapp.com/users/';
  var id = user._id
  fetch(requestUrl + id, {
      method: 'put',
      headers: {
        ...authHeader(),
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({[keys._1]:  this.props.code})
    })
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is actually trying to accomplish. See Karel's answer.

Comment: @JaredSmith looking at the error, the compilation failed at the point he was setting the key. By my solution that solves the error. It's clear he wants to use the value of keys._1 as the key so I believe my solution will work for him.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this gives me the following error: "keys" is not defined. I edited my post and added my repo on github for you :)

Comment: @MartinSeubert it is your code, so you must know where `keys` is coming from, @Alfred is working with what you have provided.

Comment: @KarelFrajták keys is a property in my json.

Comment: @MartinSeubert I thought `keys` was an object that had a node `_1`. In essence sending the value of keys._1 as key with the value `this.props.code` to the backend.

Comment: @KarelFrajták Exactly! Wenn my body looks e.g. like this:  body: JSON.stringify({firstName:  this.props.code}) it is working fine. But  body: JSON.stringify({[keys._1]:  this.props.code}) gives me the error: "keys" is not defined

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear, I dont want the values as my new keys. I just want to overwrite my old values!

I tried this one:

```
  body: JSON.stringify({[user.keys[[this.props.matchId]]]: this.props.code})
```

But in my developer tools, it just looks like this:

[image]

It takes the value as my key, but I dont want that. It should look like that:

```
{key._1: true}
```